# Intel HAXM installation error and hyper-v doesn't exist - This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x)

Tags: android

I have an issue with my HAXM installation. Here is the thing. I got this error every single time I tried to install HAXM for my computer: 
ps: i dont have hyper-v option in my computer 
please help i really need it

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2kLM.png

Comment: What is the make and model of your system? It may need to be enabled in BIOS (UEFI) but it depends on whether your system board and CPU support it and if the CPU is an Intel processor.

Comment: This probably belongs on [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had this trouble this morning and I just enabled virtualization option

### ## do this ##

*go to computer's Bios and enable virtualization*.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `Hyper-V` installed and enabled. When this is the case, then **disable** Hyper-V, because HAXM cannot run at the same time. When it is not installed, then you don't have to install it for this step. Then this is not the cause of the problem.

And maybe this link can help:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/03/14/troubleshooting-intel-haxm